# How I can identify methods declared in .smali file?

Tags: android, python, decompiler, smali, apktool

I want to extracts method  from all .smalli file . 
 Is there any format to declare methods(API Functions)  in .smalli file so i can easily extract it using python script.
I am looking for  concept so I can identify  how 1. User-define function 2. API function 3. API call sequence  are defined and declared .I want to print only API functions and API call sequence using python .

Comment: Do you mean smali or dex? Enjarify parses dex files and is written in Python.

Comment: i mean smali. i want to extract API functions from .smali file but I am not able to understand which are API functions. Is there any special way to define API functions so that i can identify them  from .smalli file . I want to extract API call sequence also , So is there any ways with which i can identify API call sequence and extract it.

Answer (score 0):

The question asks about parsing smali files, but that is unlikely to be what you actually want. Assuming your goal is to analyze Android applications, you need to parse **dex** files. Luckily, there is a tool written in Python called [Enjarify](https://github.com/Storyyeller/Enjarify) that contains a dex parser. It's not designed to be used as a library, so it will take a little bit of work to integrate, but you should be able to figure it out pretty easily. You can start by looking at [parsedex.py](https://github.com/Storyyeller/enjarify/blob/master/enjarify/parsedex.py).

Assuming that you really do want to parse smali files for some reason, things are a lot harder, as smali is a file format defined by the smali tool, which is written in Java. However, you could use Jython to call it from Python.

Comment: Thanks , I want to extract functions and API call sequence from .smalli file and I  want to create feature vector for my research work. I have used baksmali tool to convert calsses.dex into .smalli files. for ex. Landroid/app/Activity;-><init> is method(Activity methods is written like this). I dont want user defined methods but only android API like loadjar(), setcomponent() etc.  then how to identify system API and call sequence. Currently I am looking concepts point of view to understand .smalli file and how can I identify system API , Call sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Following is Syntax that is used to identify .Smali Function calls

1. invoke-super vx, vy,  :   invokes the parent classes method in object vx, passing in parameter(s) vy.
2. invoke-direct vx, vy  :  invokes a method in object vx with parameters vy, … without the virtual method resolution.
3. invoke-virtual vx, vy :  invokes the virtual method in object vx, passing in parameters vy.

Following links provide good source to start with .smalli file 
https://apkudo.com/?p=775